# Render JSON to Dynamic HTML Table

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

I have been sent some JSON

I have been asked to display this in a dynamic HTML table, the "u_status_information" section of the JSON may have different and additional variable name, so the table headers need to be based on what is received on a per message basis.

I need to do this using JavaScript.

They want the table to look like the below.

[image: TABLE IMAGE]

I have started focusing on the data extraction (Prior to rendering in HTML) and I have managed to get the top level headers and values using the code snippet below, but for the "u_status_information" section, it is unexpectedly returning "[object, object], [object, object], [object, object]".

What do I need to do to get into that part of the data?

Here is my attempt

```js
var statInfo = [{
  "u_equipment_type": "MSS",
  "u_equipment_reference": "M1/1234A",
  "u_status_time": "2019-01-22 15:30:00",
  "u_status_information": [{
    "status_name": "amber_flasher_failed",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }, {
    "status_name": "aspect_failed",
    "status_value": "FAULTY",
    "status_additional_info": "30"
  }, {
    "status_name": "some_other_fault",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }]
}, {
  "u_equipment_type": "MSS",
  "u_equipment_reference": "M1/1234A",
  "u_status_time": "2019-01-22 15:35:00",
  "u_status_information": [{
    "status_name": "amber_flasher_failed",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }, {
    "status_name": "aspect_failed",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }, {
    "status_name": "some_other_fault",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }]
}]

// EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER.
var vals = [];
for (var i = 0; i < statInfo.length; i++) {
  for (var key in statInfo[i]) {
    if (vals.indexOf(key) === -1) {
      vals.push(key);
      gs.print(key);
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < statInfo.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < vals.length; j++) {
    gs.print(statInfo[i][vals[j]]);
  }
}
```

[image: Current Output]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't add my workings up to this point - main thread now updated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a beginning:

Work in progress: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/m7Lg1yt8/

```js
var statInfo = [{
  "u_equipment_type": "MSS",
  "u_equipment_reference": "M1/1234A",
  "u_status_time": "2019-01-22 15:30:00",
  "u_status_information": [{
    "status_name": "amber_flasher_failed",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }, {
    "status_name": "aspect_failed",
    "status_value": "FAULTY",
    "status_additional_info": "30"
  }, {
    "status_name": "some_other_fault",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }]
}, {
  "u_equipment_type": "MSS",
  "u_equipment_reference": "M1/1234A",
  "u_status_time": "2019-01-22 15:35:00",
  "u_status_information": [{
    "status_name": "amber_flasher_failed",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }, {
    "status_name": "aspect_failed",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }, {
    "status_name": "some_other_fault",
    "status_value": "HEALTHY",
    "status_additional_info": ""
  }]
}]

// EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER.
var thd = document.getElementById("th"), trh = document.createElement("tr"), td;

Object.keys(statInfo[0]).forEach(function(outerKey) {
  if (typeof statInfo[0][outerKey] == "object") {
    Object.keys(statInfo[0][outerKey][0]).forEach(function(key) {
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.className="sub";
      th.textContent=key;
      trh.appendChild(th);
    })
  }
  else {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.textContent=outerKey;
    trh.appendChild(th);
  }
});
thd.appendChild(trh)
```

```css
th { border: 1px solid black; padding:3px }
td { border: 1px solid black; padding:3px }
.sub { color:red}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead id="th"></thead>
  <tbody id="tb"></tbody>
</table>
```